# Как организовать хостинг для международного сайта, чтобы получить приемлемый пинг?

Tags: хостинг, azure, amazon

Насколько я понял если выбрать обычный виртуальный хостинг в одной из стран (США, Германия, Россия) пользователи в др. странах получат высокий пинг.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему высокого пинга нельзя решить просто выбором хостинга - т.к. хостинг все равно будет одной точкой на карте, и откуда-нибудь до нее будет высокий пинг.

Вам нужен Content Distribution Network - CDN. Есть варианты с

- Отдельным CDN (например, [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)) поверх существующего хостинга.
- Родным CDN для того хостера, у которого сейчас размещен ваш сайт (Amazon CloudFront, Azure CDN, Azure TrafficManager).
- Хостингом со встроенной поддержкой CDN (например, [WPEngine](http://WPEngine.com)).

Comment: Только лишь CDN не решит проблемы. Необходимо разрабатывать тогда уж георазделенное приложение с синхронизирующимися базами данных, CDN'нами и прочим. Я на эту тему дипломную писал.

Comment: @WalterNuss для сайта (т.е. статики, или контента, где количество чтений >> количества записей, типа Stack Overflow) - решит. Для приложения - да, согласен, придется наворачивать, с использованием того же  Azure TrafficManager.

Comment: ну да в принципе. Для статических сайтов CDN'a будет достаточно.